# compatibility between astrological stars according to two dates of birth in c#

Tags: c#

i have a question about my little project which is based on the checking the compatibility between two astrological stars by checking two dates of birth (e.g: date of birth of first person(1-19(first digit represents month and 2nd digit represents date)) then second person's dob is entered accordingly.my code is working properly when i am entering two dates of birth means it is telling the month,date and astrological star according to the dates of birth entered. but when i am trying to find the compatibility between two specific stars it is only calculating the first result in if else statement,if result in first if else control structure is not found it is not jumping to the next else if statement, it is directly jumping to the last else statement..
i am first time posting the question here please help me..if anyone can here is my code sample!!!

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Month:" + date.Month);
            Console.WriteLine("Day:" + date.Day);
            month = date.Month;
            day = date.Day;
            month1=date1.Month;
            day1=date1.Day;
string[] stringArr = { "January", "February", "march", "April", "may", "June", "July", "august", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
                if (day <= 19)
                    return "Capricorn";
                else
                    return "Aquarius";

            case 2:
                if (day <= 18)
                    return "Aquarius";
                else
                    return "Pisces";
            case 3:
                if (day <= 20)
                    return "Pisces";
                else
                    return "Aries";
            case 4:
                if (day <= 19)
                    return "Aries";
                else
                    return "Taurus";
            case 5:
                if (day <= 20)
                    return "Taurus";
                else
                    return "Gemini";
            case 6:
                if (day <= 20)
                    return "Gemini";
                else
                    return "Cancer";
            case 7:
                if (day <= 22)
                    return "Cancer";
                else
                    return "Leo";
            case 8:
                if (day <= 22)
                    return "Leo";
                else
                    return "Virgo";
            case 9:
                if (day <= 22)
                    return "Virgo";
                else
                    return "Libra";
            case 10:
                if (day <= 22)
                    return "Libra";
                else
                    return "Scorpio";
            case 11:
                if (day <= 21)
                    return "Scorpio";
                else
                    return "Sagittarius";
            case 12:
                if (day <= 21)
                    return "Sagittarius";
                else
                    return "Capricorn";

        return "";
       }
```

date of birth for another person is calculated simultaneously.
problem is here..

```
if (ob.month.Equals(1) && ob1.month1.Equals(1))
{

    if (ob.day <= 19 && ob1.day1 <= 19)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Compatibility of Capricon with Capricon");
    }
    // else if (ob.day <= 19 && ob1.day1 > 19)
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Compatibility of Capricon with Aquarius");
    }
}

else if (ob.month.Equals(1) && ob.month1.Equals(2))
{

    if (ob.day <= 19 && ob1.day1 <= 18)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Compatibility of Capricon with Aquarius");
    }
    //else if (ob.day <= 19 && ob1.day1 > 18)
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Compatibility of Capricon with Pisces");
    }
}
else if (ob.month.Equals(1) && ob.month1.Equals(3))
{
    if (ob.day <= 19 && ob.day1 <= 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Compatibility of Capricon with Pisces");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Compatibility of Capricon with Aries");
    }
}
else
    {consle.writeLine("invalid");
    }
```

this code is giving response just to 1st if else statement not to other if else..
please help me..how should i solve this problem!!!

Comment: You have taken so much of effort to write this question :)

Answer (score 1):

You make it very difficult way. Make it simpler.

```
class Program
{
    enum ZodiacSign
    {
        Aries, // March 21 - April 20
        Taurus, // April 21 - May 21
        Gemini, // May 22 - June 21
        Cancer, // June 22 - July 22
        Leo, // July 23 -August 21
        Virgo, // August 22 - September 23
        Libra, // September 24 - October 23
        Scorpio, // October 24 - November 22
        Sagittarius, // November 23 - December 22
        Capricorn, // December 23 - January 20
        Aquarius, // January 21 - February 19
        Pisces // February 20- March 20
    }

    static ZodiacSign BirthdayToZodiacSign(DateTime birthday)
    {
        var periodEndList = new[] {
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 1, 20), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Capricorn },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 2, 19), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Aquarius },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 3, 20), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Pisces },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 4, 20), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Aries },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 5, 21), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Taurus },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 6, 21), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Gemini },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 7, 22), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Cancer },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 8, 21), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Leo },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 9, 23), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Virgo },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 10, 23), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Libra },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 11, 22), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Scorpio },
            new { PeriodEnd = new DateTime(birthday.Year, 12, 22), ZodiacSign = ZodiacSign.Sagittarius }
        };

        foreach (var periodEnd in periodEndList)
            if (birthday <= periodEnd.PeriodEnd)
                return periodEnd.ZodiacSign;
        return ZodiacSign.Capricorn;
    }

    static string GenerateCompatibilityString(DateTime birthday1, DateTime birthday2)
    {
        return string.Format("Compatibility of {0} with {1}", BirthdayToZodiacSign(birthday1), BirthdayToZodiacSign(birthday2));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GenerateCompatibilityString(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), new DateTime(2014, 6, 7)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't completely read your code (as it seems incomplete, e.g. what is `ob`), but here's a general comment:

If you have an `if else-if`  construct, then only one branch will be executed. E.g. in the following example, only one code-block will be executed (the one corresponding to the first condition evaluating to `true`):

```
if (condition1)
{}
else if (condition2)
{}
else if (condition3)
{}
else
{}
```

If you have several conditions which can evaluate to `true`, then you should use multiple `if` statements instead:

```
if (condition1)
{}
if (condition2)
{}
if (condition3)
{}
// if you need an "else" part:
if (!condition1 && !condition2 && !condition3)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple class that solves this problem:

```
public class Signs
{
  static List<string> SignList = new List<string>() {
    "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces", "Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Not Found" };

  static List<int> StartDates = new List<int>() {
    // month * 100 + day of month
     120, 219, 320, 420, 521, 621, 722, 821, 923, 1023, 1122, 1222, 1232, 9999 // edge marker
  };

  static public string Sign(DateTime inDate)
  {
    return SignList[StartDates.TakeWhile(d => (inDate.Month*100)+inDate.Day > d).Count()];
  }
}
```

There is another version that might be clearer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23183480/215752